# What is this song from The Santa Clause 3?

Tags: identify-this-song

This song is featured instrumentally in the "Christmas Sweet" by George Clinton from *The Santa Clause 3*, and I think it's a traditional Christmas carol. Can anyone identify it?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyVXMNZo-Gk&feature=youtu.be&t=7m21s (from around 7:24 in this link).

https://soundcloud.com/user8372218/1-the-santa-clause-suite (around 4:09 in this link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recognize it as a traditional Christmas carol, but it does have hints of "[I Saw Three Ships (Come Sailing In)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rc8CQwMmd0)."